# Integrate CKEditor with ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ckeditor

I'm new in programming please help me.The situation is I have a webfilemanager to browse specific path in my directory, what I need is when user click on the file in the directory, the file will open in CKEditor and user can edit or update the file and then save them.I have use language asp.net,C# and vb.net.Anyone have a suggestion example for me.

Thank a lot for advice!

Comment: are you using webforms

Comment: Did you try searching it on Google....??

Comment: http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/423_Upload_Images_and_Integrate_with_CKeditor_in_AspNet.aspx take a look at this tutorial

Comment: I already search in google, but I not find the example